# WebGrid binding in GET method but not in POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, webgrid

While binding the List of values from `GET` method the `WebGrid` is displaying the data and same is not displaying in `POST` method.

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
     public ActionResult Index()
       {

                 ObservableCollection<Product> inventoryList = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
                inventoryList.Add(new Product { Id = "P101", Name = "Computer", Description = "All type of computers", Quantity = 800 });
                inventoryList.Add(new Product { Id = "P102", Name = "Laptop", Description = "All models of Laptops", Quantity = 500 });
                inventoryList.Add(new Product { Id = "P103", Name = "Camera", Description = "Hd  cameras", Quantity = 300 });
                inventoryList.Add(new Product { Id = "P104", Name = "Mobile", Description = "All Smartphones", Quantity = 450 });
                inventoryList.Add(new Product { Id = "P105", Name = "Notepad", Description = "All branded of notepads", Quantity = 670 });
                inventoryList.Add(new Product { Id = "P106", Name = "Harddisk", Description = "All type of Harddisk", Quantity = 1200 });
                inventoryList.Add(new Product { Id = "P107", Name = "PenDrive", Description = "All type of Pendrive", Quantity = 370 });
                return View(inventoryList);
       }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Reports(string name)
  {
          ObservableCollection<Product> inventoryList = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
                    inventoryList.Add(new Product { Id = "P101", Name = "Computer", Description = "All type of computers", Quantity = 800 });
                    inventoryList.Add(new Product { Id = "P102", Name = "Laptop", Description = "All models of Laptops", Quantity = 500 });
                    inventoryList.Add(new Product { Id = "P103", Name = "Camera", Description = "Hd  cameras", Quantity = 300 });
                    inventoryList.Add(new Product { Id = "P104", Name = "Mobile", Description = "All Smartphones", Quantity = 450 });
                    inventoryList.Add(new Product { Id = "P105", Name = "Notepad", Description = "All branded of notepads", Quantity = 670 });
                    inventoryList.Add(new Product { Id = "P106", Name = "Harddisk", Description = "All type of Harddisk", Quantity = 1200 });
                    inventoryList.Add(new Product { Id = "P107", Name = "PenDrive", Description = "All type of Pendrive", Quantity = 370 });
                    return View(inventoryList);
 }
```

**View:**

```
@{
var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow",ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);}
    <div id="gridContent">
    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
            headerStyle: "header",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            selectedRowStyle: "select",
            columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Id", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.Id)),
            grid.Column("Name", " Name"),
            grid.Column("Description", "Description", style: "description"),
            grid.Column("Quantity", "Quantity")
     )) 

</div>
```

Can someone help me in this?

Comment: is there any special reason to use POST method to fetch data? web API standard doesn't tell us to use POST to fetch data. => GET, to retrieve a copy of the resource at the specified URI. The body of the response message contains the details of the requested resource.
=> POST, to create a new resource at the specified URI. The body of the request message provides the details of the new resource. Note that POST can also be used to trigger operations that don't actually create resources.

Comment: The GET works when the page is loaded. For the POST method i'm passing few parameters to filter the data. Have updated the question.

Comment: did you try to return a json result to see if there is any value returning?